# Действие кнопки Home в Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

Здравствуйте!

Недавно перешел с `ActionBar` на `Toolbar`. Как и раньше, использую в связке с `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, но сталкиваюсь с проблемой постоянной потребности обрабатывать вручную нажатия по стрелке. 
Например, если из одного фрагмента перешли в другой, приходится самому устанавливать значение для тулбара:

```
   mActivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mActivity.getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Возможно,  в этом конкретном сценарии спорно ожидать иного.

Но в случае, если я нажимаю на стрелку "назад", я хочу вернуться к предыдущему фрагменту, а у меня открывается боковое меню.
Совершенно не понятно как работать с этим прекрасным нововведением.

Кроме того, в примерах встречаю связку только с `ActionBarActivity`, если я правильно понимаю то этот класс больше не поддерживается (deprecated). У меня хост-активити расширяет `FragmentActivity`.

Еще есть проблема, в случае если мы хотим подтвердить/отменить какое либо действие. 
В моей имплементации я просто показываю поверх тулбара свою разметку. А как это правильно сделать используюя тулбар?

Подобные примеры использования можно увидеть при создании письма в GMail и Mail.ru почте

Answer (score 1):

А не надо ничего пытаться понимать - у меня такое ощущение, что этим тайным знанием владеют считанные единицы людей. Если у вас нет желания потратить пару недель своей жизни на это тайное знание, то советую взять внешнюю либу типа [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

Я лично потратил пару дней на уяснение механизма работы стрелок, тулбаров, *hamburger icon* и проч. прелестей, но не преуспел: запутался в версиях API, суппорт библиотек и т.д., перешел на указанную либу и почти счастлив.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, действие этой кнопки можно обработать самостоятельно следующим образом:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // действие по нажатию на кнопку home
            return true;
        default:return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

PS: `ActionBarActivity` была объявлена *deprecated* после появления `AppCompatActivity` и устаревшая она только по отношению именно к ней, так как вторая лучше реализует взаимодействие с библиотекой `appcompat` - то есть вместо `ActionBarActivity` рекомендовано использовать `AppCompatActivity` когда это требуется и все.

**UPD** PPS: Для реализации подтверждения\отмены действий используются диалоги, либо [`SnackBar`](https://www.google.ru/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage) , а вообще в одном вопросе можно спрашивать решение одной проблемы, по другой проблеме *( aka "а еще хотел спросить .." )* создавайте новый вопрос.

Comment: В том то и дело, что на каждый сценарий приходится обработку самому делать. Мне казалось что с `ActionBar` несколько проще было.

Comment: `ActionBar` точно также не реализовывал функциональность кнопки  home - она только отображалась, но ее действие требовалось прописывать самому явно.